# How to normalize an array of arrays?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matrix, plot

I got an array that is 27x5 and basically contains 5 1D plots. Is there a way to normalize each of these plots by the last one?

```
matrix \= matrix[:,-1]
```

does not work.

Afterwards I plot them by saying. and get 5 plots

```
plt.plot(matrix[:27,:])
```

Comment: What do you want to do for the first 1D plot?

Answer (score 0):

`matrix \= matrix[:,-1].reshape(27,1)` works